# question about internal , external and boundary set of a real interval

Tags: real-analysis

I have a set of real points $(0,2) \cup  \left \{ 3 \right \}$ and

it is asked to find the set of internal points, of external points and of boundary point.

In my opinion the set of internal points is $E^i=(0,2)$,

the set of external points is $E^e=(\infty ,0) \cup (2,\infty)$ because 3 should be an external point 
and the boundary set $\left \{ 0,2 \right \}$ .

I have some doubt about the external set and the boundary set.

Comment: How can a point be external of itself lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember that $A^e = X \setminus \bar{A}$, where $X$ is the *universe* or total set. Then you can easily compute $\bar{E} = [0, 2] \cup \{3\}$.

As @Kenny Lau noted, $a \in A \implies a \in \bar{A} \implies a \notin X \setminus \bar{A} = A^e$. Intuitionally, a point of a set *may* not lay in its interior (deep within the set), but it can't possibly be in the exterior (far away from the set).

---

I take it from your comment that you're not familiarized with the general topology concepts, so let's stick to $\Bbb R$ and intervals.

First of all, note that your definition of external point, although fundamentally true, is rather impractical, since checking that a given point is external would require to find an interval of external points, for which we'd have to find such an interval for each of the interval points... and so on and so forth. Fortunately, it's equivalent to a much easier definition (check it):

$$ a \in A^e \iff \exists x < a < y: (x, y) \cap A = \emptyset $$

Now for $ E = (0, 2) \cup \{3\} $ it's quite clear that the *problematic* points are $0, 2$ and $3$, for if $x \in (0, 2)$ then $x \in \mathring{E}$ (where $\mathring{A} = A^i$ denotes the interior set).

Of course, for $x \in \{0, 2, 3\}, \alpha < x < \beta, I = (\alpha, \beta)$ we have 
$$ I \cap E \ne \emptyset, I \cap (\Bbb R \setminus E) = I \setminus E \ne \emptyset \implies x \in \partial E $$
(where $\partial A$ denotes the boundary)

Finally, if $x \notin \mathring{E} \cup \partial E = (0, 2) \cup \{0, 2, 3\} = [0, 2] \cup \{3\} = \bar{E}$, i.e., it's not in $E$'s interior nor its boundary, then it must be in the exterior $E^e$, so $E^e = \Bbb R \setminus ([0, 2] \cup \{3\}) = (-\infty, 0) \cup (2, 3) \cup (3, +\infty)$

Comment: I've studied that a point is external if it is possibile to have an interval of all external points. It is clear to me that 3 is internal but it isn't possible to have an interval of  3 of internal points

Comment: @Anne check my edit, hope it helps

Comment: Thanks, I think I understood

Comment: @Anne then you may accept/upvote the answer